# jQuery siblings / removeClass "active" just wont work

Tags: jquery, removeclass, siblings

I've been trying to get this arrow toggle script work on my page. I think i miss something simple but I just don't know what is it. Been spending 2 hrs to figure this out.

The script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".accordion h3:first").addClass("active");
    $(".accordion a:first").addClass("active");
    $(".accordion p:not(:first)").hide();

    $(".accordion h3").click(function() 
    {
        $(this).next("p").slideDown("slow")
               .siblings("p:visible").slideUp("slow");
    });

    $(".accordion a").click(function() 
    {
        $(this).css({background:"url(images/arrowdown.gif) bottom right no-repeat"});
        $(this).siblings("a").removeClass("active");
    });  
});
```

css:

```
.accordion h3 a {
    padding:20px 0 0 190px; 
    display:block;  
    background:url(images/arrowup.gif) no-repeat bottom right; }

.accordion h3 a:hover { text-decoration:none;   }

.accordion h3 a.active {
    background:url(images/arrowdown.gif) no-repeat bottom right; }
```

Then my HTML :

```
<div class="accordion">
    <h3 id="tab1">
        <a href="#">Title 1</a>
    </h3>
    <p>Description Title 1</p>
    <h3 id="tab2">
        <a href="#">Title 2</a>
    </h3>
    <p>Description Title 2</p>
    <h3 id="tab3">
        <a href="#">Title 3</a>
    </h3>
    <p>Description Title 3</p>
</div>
```

So the up & down arrow is INSIDE the "a href" tag and there is a different background image in H3 tag depends on the "tab" ID. I hope that make senses.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `siblings` works for elements under the same parent. Your `a` links are not under the same parent since each one is wrapped in a `h3`.

So I believe this is what you want

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".accordion h3:first").addClass("active");
    $(".accordion a:first").addClass("active");
    $(".accordion p:not(:first)").hide();

    $(".accordion h3").click(function() {
        $(this)
            .addClass('active') //set the current as active
            .siblings("h3") //find sibling h3 elements
            .removeClass("active") // and remove the active from them
            .end() // return selection to the current element
            .next("p") // find the next p
            .slideDown("slow") // and show it
            .siblings("p:visible") // find the other visible p elements
            .slideUp("slow"); // and hide them

        $(this)
            .find('a') // find a under current element
            .addClass('active') // and add active class
            .end() // return to current element
            .siblings('h3') // find sibling h3 elements
            .find('a') // find their a elements
            .removeClass('active'); // and remove the active
    });

});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/NSvQB/

Comment: wow ! work like a charm. I still reading this code, trying to understand what did I do wrong...thanks a million !

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors in the script:

1. Each `<a>` element is the only child an `<h3>` element. There are no other `<a>` siblings. What you want is to find all other `<a>` element inside the headers of the accordion:

   ```
   $(this).closest('.accordion').find('h3 a').removeClass("active");
   ```
2. Setting the style on an element (`$(this).css(...);`) will overwrite any other style definitions. Changes to the background later via changing a class (in this case, removing the class `active`) [will not have any effect *<sup>[demo]</sup>*](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/fqBnx/). So instead of setting the style directly, you should set the `active` class:

   ```
   $(this).addClass('active');
   ```

Working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/2Rt5v/)

---

**Update:** You could also simplify the whole code by putting everything into the `h3` click event handler and even add the `active` class to it.

JavaScript:

```
$(".accordion h3").click(function() {

    $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass('active');

    $(this).next("p").slideDown("slow")
           .siblings("p:visible").slideUp("slow");

});
```

CSS (changed part):

```
.accordion h3.active a {
    background:red; 
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/fqBnx/)